# how can I build and iphone app which tracks a users location uploads the coordinates

Tags: iphone, maps, location, coordinates

I am writing an app for iphone to go along site my website which tracks the location of the user. Can anyone give me any pointers on where to begin. I am very good with mysql and php etc but I am a novice with iphone apps.

The coordinates from the app need to be able to upload to my api which I have set up.

Thanks

Comment: First of all you need a mac, do you have one?

Comment: yes i just need help with the above

Comment: u might wanna have a look at CLLocation API and also a sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html. The location can be got as lat and long. Once got, I beleive you know how to send it to your server from the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is create a simple app that can run in the background.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

During background execution you cannot do anything really too much with the network so I suggest logging it using [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) and then on resume/startup to send an HTTP post to a PHP page that logs it into your DB?

Comment: thanks for that Lee. How are the coordinates sent though because my site is reading them as (lng,lat),(lng,lat) etc - is this how the app will send them?

Comment: You can configure how you want really.  The app will store them as a CLLocation which you can get the individual components out as a double which you can then convert to a string and POST to the web server.  You will be able to construct the HTTP POST to exactly as you say above

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [HTML5 geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html). Also reading "Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript" is recommended. I read the same book for Android and was very pleased. Building your app in HTML5/CSS/JS will also mean that it will probably work on other platforms.

Comment: i dont think its possible to continually update with a webapp though is it?

Comment: If you want it to run in the background you're looking at a solution Lee Armstrong provided.